# Sum of Bernoulli random variables with different success probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{i} \in \{0,1\}$ be Bernouli random variable with probability of success $p_{i}$, i.e., $P(X_{i}=1) = p_{i}$ and $P(X_{i}=0) = 1-p_{i}$ and let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ for $n>0$. Is it relatively simple to estimate the pmf $P(Y=y)$ when $p_{i} \neq p_{j}$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: Not quite iid, the $p_i$ are not the same.

Comment: Answer: not in the general case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are describing is called a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) (PBD). In what sense do you want to estimate it?

If you are looking to some approximate learning of the distribution, based on samples drawn from it, you can have a look at [this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/papers/stoc12pbd.html). It gives a (randomized) algorithm which, given access to i.i.d. draws from a PBD $p$ and a parameter $\varepsilon>0$, uses $\tilde{O}(\varepsilon^{-3})$ samples (no dependence on $n$), runs in polynomial time (in $\log n$ and $\varepsilon^{-1}$) and with high probability, outputs a representation of a probability distribution which is close (in terms of statistical distance — that is, $L_1$ distance, up to a factor 2) to the distribution $p$.

The distribution outputted by the algorithm is not a PBD, though; if you insist on getting a PBD, this is possible with the same number of samples, but a blowup in the running time of the algorithm (now superpolynomial in $\varepsilon^{-1}$).

*Remarks:* $\tilde{O}(\varepsilon^{-3})$ means $O(\varepsilon^{-3}\mathrm{poly}(\log(\varepsilon^{-1})))$ (the tilde "hides" the logarithmic factors).

Comment: This is a very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer!

Comment: Very good answer!!!