# Calculating the Probability of N people attending the wedding.

Tags: probability

I have a list of N invitees to whom I have sent the invitation. I know the individual probabilities of each invitee attending the wedding. I would like to calculate the number of invitees who are likely to attend the wedding. How do I calculate this?

Comment: By likely do you mean most probable value, or expected value?

Comment: When you say "how do I calculate this?", what do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

We can treat each invitee as a Bernoulli distribution and the number of invitees who attend as the sum of $N$ of such Bernoulli distributions. Assuming independence, we can get the expectation by $ E(X)=\displaystyle \sum_i^N p_{i=1}$ (i.e. sum of individual probabilities).

If we are interested in the most probable value, (i.e. the mode), I think more analysis will be needed. If all the individual probabilities are the same then the number of invitees attending will follow a Binomial distribution and the mode is known for such cases (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode_and_median)). If the probabilities are not the same, I do not know of a simple method. (Only one that comes to mind is getting the probability distribution function by brute force (counting over all possible subsets) and then proceeding to maximize the probability.)

Comment: you don't need independence...expectation is linear

Comment: Kevin is correct that the general PMF is not nice to calculate. See this related thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392860/sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-with-different-success-probabilities. If you are looking for an approximate answer, you can try using the BetaBinomial distribution, where you fit a beta distribution to the distribution of acceptance probabilities. That might get you a rough estimate.