# Probability of a Poisson-Bernoulli Random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a random variable $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$ where each $X_i$ is a bernoulli variable with success probability $p_i$.

What's the most efficient way to calculate P(Y = y) with $y \in [0, n] $?

Edit: For those interested, I found the following paper which has a few methods:
http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A7n44.pdf

Comment: For those who tried to answer this and failed, could you provide a short answer?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392860/sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-with-different-success-probabilities