# Appropriate weights for weighted sum of finite number of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $\left\{X_{{1}}, X_{{2}}, \ldots, X_{k}\right\}$ denotes Bernoulli random variables with $\quad\left[p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots, p_{k}\right]$ as respective parameters. Let

> > $S=a_1X_{{1}}+a_2X_{{2}}+\ldots+a_kX_{k}$.

where  $a_i > 0$ and $a_i \neq 0,  \forall i \in {1,2,\ldots,k}$

Note that all $p_i$ values are closer to $0$ (but not equal to) and they are different. Moreover, $k$ is not too large to invoke asymptotic approximations or not too small.

> > What are some suitable weights  $a_i$'s such that the distribution of $S$ has a closed form?

Note that the trivial solution of $a_i=constant$ is not useful  for me.  Some possibility of weights I could consider are as follows:

1. $a_i=i \implies S=X_{{1}}+2X_{{2}}+\ldots+kX_{k}$ . Does the distribution of S have a closed form in this case.?
2. $a_i =q^{i-1} \implies S=X_{{1}}+q^1X_{{2}}+\ldots+q^{k-1
   }X_{k}$ . This has geometric weights.
3. $a_i=1/i \implies S=X_{{1}}+(1/2)X_{{2}}+\ldots+(1/k)X_{k}$

I am flexible with choosing any weight sets as long as they are all positives and unique.

Comment: If $0 \leq q \leq 1/2 $, the geometric weight one is uniform on some set of rational numbers. (it can be represented in base n (if q is 1/n for some integer n). In particular, if q = 1/2, you can show that that sum converges to a uniform distribution in [0,2].

Comment: @E-A, Could you elaborate this? I am ok with $0<q\leq0.5$. I am not able to understand how the sum converges to  $U~[0,2]$, when $q$ is 1/2. Also, if the number of random variables (k)  is not too large to invoke asymptotic approximations, does it hold.

Comment: We can quite explicitly write the distribution of 

$$ S_k = \frac{1}{2} X_1 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 X_2 + ... + (\frac{1}{2})^k X_k $$

through it probability mass function, which puts weight $(\frac{1}{2})^k$ on $\frac{j}{2^k}$ for all $j \in \{0, ..., 2^k - 1\}$.

Comment: @E-A , It seems wrong to me. $S_1=\frac{1}{2}X_{1}$ is not uniform as $X_1$ is bernoulli with probability $p_1$. Are you assuming  $k\rightarrow \infty$? (I have finite k)

Comment: Yeah, the asymptotic was for k tending to infinity. Also just realized that the first case can be partially done counting partitions with distinct parts, but I don't know enough number theory to do it.

Comment: The $p_i$'s are arbitrary, so even asymptotically in the $q=1/2$ case we don't end up with uniform, since each bit in the binary representation is $1$ with a different probability.  In fact, I'd say the case of $a_i = $constant is not trivial at all.  It has a name though, Poisson Binomial Distribution, according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392860/sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-with-different-success-probabilities)

Comment: @antkam, Yes. you are right. Even when all the weights are unity, it is not having a closed-form distribution.  I was hoping if there exists a nicer set of weights where I could have a closed-form.

Comment: If you have arbitrary $p_i$ given by an adversary, then, for all practical purposes, the answer, most likely, is "there is no way to get a closed form for the distribution under any useful meaning of the notion of "closed form", though the formal proof of that may be difficult and requires a long discussion of and agreement on some "meta-mathematical" definitions. So I would rather ask why you want closed form at all, i.e., what exactly you are going to achieve with it.

Comment: @fedja, say, if I am okay with having my weights as a function of $p_i$, do you think it is still intractable?

Comment: As requested, yes, because even describing the exact support of the resulting probability measure is a nightmare unless there is some arithmetic relation between the weights, forget the distribution.